# Is it possible to read URL and restrict the GET request coming from third party app to Salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, apexrest, connected-apps, third-party

My requirement is to make the API calls from any third party app to salesforce using OAuth2.0

So, I created "Connected App" within Salesforce and from the generated "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret", I am making the calls from POSTMAN to Salesforce using OAuth2.0 authorization. And I have created two Rest APIs within Salesforce which will execute the calls and will send the data as response.

But my problem is, I would like to make the API calls only for REST API. I knew that there are some standard API calls within Salesforce to retrieve the data like

```
https://{domain}/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Account/{ID}
```

But I would like to restrict all other API calls except the calls which are having "/apexrest/" within the URL.

Is it possible to do like this? Please advice.

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to restrict all other "standard API" calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't restrict user to access standard rest/soap endpoint i.e. `/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Account` but API that access your organization's Salesforce data are subject to the same security protections that are used in the Salesforce user interface.

It means they will only have access to the objects/records where permission is granted at profile level.

Comment: Yes, That is the exact issue for me @Himanshu. I don't want to show all the data to that particular user. Only some records need to be shown. And I can't change the OWD or Profile access for a single user. I cannot create n number of profiles and permission sets for n number of users.

Comment: How you are handling this on UI?

Comment: I have made the user as "API Only User". Even the user tries to log in from UI, There it will show as Insufficient privileges and if any tab is clicked, the user will return back to login page automatically.

Comment: remove object Read permission to handle your scenario.

Comment: Okay. I will explain clearly to you. There is one company called "X" where the products of "X" are using by many companies like "A", "B", "C", "D", etc..., For each company, there will be a record within Account Object and the representatives (contacts) for that particular company. I am trying to create a user who can access salesforce only through API to gather only from his/her particular account. But for now, Even though the user cannot edit all the accounts, the user can able see the accounts (including attachments of other company). And I know this is the issue of OWD which I can't change

Comment: Sharing settings?

Comment: @kurunve, I can't change the OWD settings of the Account object from "Public Read/Write" to "Private" as it will impact some other features within Communities/Portal.

Comment: @Subhash You must either change the OWD, or you must remove read access for all the objects. Since data is meant to only be exposed via the API you created, there shouldn't be any problem turning off Read permission for the entire profile.

Comment: Wow, I understand that now. While Himanshu mentioning about removing object Read permission, I didn't understand. But @sfdcfox, Thanks for the clarification. This solves my issue.